# Laravel use Stripe\Customer as StripeCustomer in Controller throws Error

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I am having an issue trying to use StripeCustomer in a controller. I need to retrieve a customer from Stripe. So I have on my controller : use Stripe\Customer as StripeCustomer; I see in cashier's Billable.php being used this way. But I try to use it in the controller I get

> Could not determine which URL to request: Stripe\Customer instance has
>   invalid ID:

Any ideas how to use Stripe\Customer within a controller? Is there a scope of namespace? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks a little like the code is being found just fine, so there is probably nothing wrong with your `use` statement.

The error message suggests you are trying to manipulate, or work with, an uninitialised Stripe\Customer object.

Your code should a little like this (taken from Stripes docs)

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_KZ3pTiXRPJ1gpqLlKlEGA3bY");
$customer = StripeCustomer::retrieve("cus_8gZXNXuq2kIsQv");
// work with $customer here... (assumes your use statement from the question)
```